# Alternatives to reflection when accessing an arbitrary field

Tags: java, reflection

I was using this code to create some sort of a universal changer class:

```
    //constructor method
    public Change(Object affdObj, String affdField, float modifier) {
        obj = affdObj;
        //...
        affectedField = affdObj.getClass().getField(affdField);
        //...
        affectedField.setFloat(obj, affectedField.getFloat(obj) + modifier);
    }
```

But then I was advised to avoid reflection whenever possible since it's very slow. I was suggested to pay attention to interfaces. Unfortunately I can't see how to fit interfaces to my code.

Hence my question: if one needs to access a field which name he *doesn't know in advance* are there any options other than using reflection?

PS

Thank you for replies, guys.

And since my question is put on hold as primarily opinion-based, I consider this to be the answer to my question, i.e. there is no other way to achieve my goal which is better than mine in every aspect. In other words, I conclude that my approach is OK. Thank you.

Comment: reflection isn't that slow, I suggest you get it working first. It takes a fraction of a micro-second if you cache the `Field` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, reflection is not slow (anymore) and is widely used (Spring uses it, Hibernate uses it, etc.). So, you use it with confidence if your only concern is speed.
Regarding  other ways to do what you want, since you provide the field name as as a string and identify it like that, you cannot do it with interfaces.